# Ember.js "template to render" versus "template to render into"

Tags: ember.js

In the last example of [Ember.js's guide about Rendering a Template](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/#toc_rendering-a-template), it says:

```
App.PostRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
      into: 'posts',                // the template to render into
      ...
```

Does this mean that "the template to render" is a [{{ partial }}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_partial), [{{ outlet }}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet), [{{ render }}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render) or [{{ template }}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_template) inside "the template to render"?

If not, can someone give an example with a route as well as a template to differentiate "template to render" and "template to render into" and show how they should be used with `this.render()`?

Answer (score 0):

The template to render is a handlebars template name. If you don't specify one Ember will assume the template name is the same as the route name: 'post'. Here you have specified 'favoritePost' as the template name instead.

The template to render into determines where to render the 'favoritePost' template. The default is the {{ outlet }} on the 'application' template. Here you have specified that the 'favoritePost' template should render into the {{ outlet }} in the 'posts' template (which should be an ancestor route).  In this way you can nest data: a list of all posts and a view of the selected post, etc.

Comment: so basically "the template to render" is specified as an {{ outlet }} inside "the template to render"?

Comment: Template to render will render into the {{ outlet }} of the template to render into.